# How to get the product category id in the cart? Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get a list of product categories id in the basket?
Here I get the name of the product.

```
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
class Collect extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    protected $_code = 'chester_collect';
    protected $_session;
    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_session = $session;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

public function isActive()
    {
        /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
        $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item){
          var_dump($item->getName());
        }          
    }
```

But how to get all the categories of goods that are in the basket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have modified your code with below code:

```
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

class Collect extends AbstractCarrier implements CarrierInterface
{
    protected $_code = 'chester_collect';
    protected $_session;
    private $_objectManager;
    public function __construct(
        Session $session,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_session = $session;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    public function isActive()
    {
        /** @var $item \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item */
        $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            var_dump($item->getName());
            $productid = $item->getProductId();
            $product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);
            $categoriesIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
            var_dump($categoriesIds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using objectManager is a bad solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Code for Getting Cart Items and get Categories Ids and names by
>   loading Products from Items

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

// retrieve quote items collection
$itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

// get array of all items what can be display directly
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

// retrieve quote items array
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $productid = $item->getProductId();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);
    $categoriesIds = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
    foreach($categoriesIds as $categoryId){
        $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($categoryId);
        echo $cat->getName();
    }
}
```

**I hope this will help.**

Comment: It is prohibited by magento to use objectManager

Answer (score 1):

I think you should avoid using the object manager where possible, as well as avoiding reloading products.

I was doing something similar around checkout and the following worked for me

```php
class MyClass
{
  /**
   * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
   */
  protected $checkoutSession;

  /**
   * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
   */
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
  ){
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
  }

  protected function myFunction()
  {
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
    foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
      $categoryIds = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
      // do some further logic
    }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can swapout checkout session with cart session if your logic isn't being triggered on the checkout page.